# Adding rows to Datatable does not work as expected

Tags: python, kivymd

My program gets data from a mariadb-database and I want to display the contents I get from the database in a table created as an instance of the MDDataTabl-class. I read that I can pass the data as a list of lists to the class.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.datatables import MDDataTable
from kivy.metrics import dp
import datetime

dataforrows=[]
dataofrow=[]

# cur is where the elements from the database query are stored in.

for (Field1,Field2,Field3) in cur:
    dataforrows.append(Field1)
    dataforrows.append(Field2)
    dataforrows.append(Field3)
    temprow=dataforrows.copy()
    dataofrow.append(temprow)
    dataforrows.clear()
print(dataofrow)
```

The construction of my list works as expected, as the output of `print(dataofrow)`to the CLI shows:

```
[['01', '2-2', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['02', '1-1', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['03', '1-8', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['07', '1-3', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['11', '1-4', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['06', '', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['10', '1-8', datetime.date(2020, 2, 28)],
['05', '2-1', datetime.date(2020, 3, 3)],
['09', '', datetime.date(2020, 3, 6)],
['08', '1-3', datetime.date(2020, 3, 6)],
['04', '', datetime.date(2020, 3, 6)]]
```

The problem arises when I try to fill the table with `dataofrow`. Only 5 items are displayed and no scrollbar is visible. Here is the snippet that creates the table:

```
table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.5},
                    column_data=[
                                ("Field1", dp(30)),
                                ("Field2", dp(30)),
                                ("Field3", dp(30))
                            ],
                    row_data=dataofrow
        )
```

Even when pasting the output manually into the sourcecode only the first 5 rows are displayed. Also filling the empty `''` with something makes no difference in the visual output.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding the "rows_num" value to the MDDataTable description as shown below. This will show 200 rows of content with scrollbar.

```
table = MDDataTable(pos_hint={'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y':0.5}, 
                rows_num=200,
                column_data=[
                            ("Field1", dp(30)),
                            ("Field2", dp(30)),
                            ("Field3", dp(30))
                        ],
                row_data=dataofrow
    )
```